# Writing to database intermittently only partly works

Tags: php, sql, database, insert, vbulletin

I have not been able to re-create the issue, it seems to only happen to one person on multiple machines..

I'm thinking, maybe something to do with the SQL.. I don't know if his ISP could have something to do with it? Like I said, the issue so far is only happening to one guy.. Multiple machines, multiple usernames to test my permissions code and its very weird..

The other 100 times i've tested it, it all works flawless.. Here is part of my code.

```
if($_REQUEST['do'] == 'save_new_vehicle') {
$userid = $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'];
$username = $vbulletin->userinfo['username'];
$vbulletin->input->clean_array_gpc('p', array(
'year' => TYPE_INT,
'make_model' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'susp_type' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'interior' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'exterior' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'audiovideo' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'wheelstires' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'suspension' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'drivetrain' => TYPE_NOHTML,
'nickname' => TYPE_NOHTML,
));  

$year = $vbulletin->GPC['year'];
$make_model = $vbulletin->GPC['make_model'];
$susp_type = $vbulletin->GPC['susp_type'];
$interior = $vbulletin->GPC['interior'];
$exterior = $vbulletin->GPC['exterior'];
$audio_video = $vbulletin->GPC['audiovideo'];
$wheels_tires = $vbulletin->GPC['wheelstires'];
$suspension = $vbulletin->GPC['suspension'];
$drivetrain = $vbulletin->GPC['drivetrain'];
$nickname = $vbulletin->GPC['nickname'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO ". TABLE_PREFIX ."BAMFG_vehicle (

  userid, 
  username, 
  nickname, 
  year, 
  make_model,
  susp_type,
  exterior,
  interior,
  audio_video,
  drivetrain,
  suspension,
  wheels_tires) VALUES (

  '". $userid ."',
  '". $username ."',
  '". $nickname ."',
  '". $year ."',
  '". $make_model ."',
  '". $susp_type ."',  
  '". $exterior ."',
  '". $interior ."',
  '". $drivetrain ."',
  '". $audio_video ."',
  '". $suspension ."',
  '". $wheels_tires ."')";
$db->query_write($sql);
}
```

It will write: year, make_model, susp_type, interior, exterior and audio_video.. nothing else for this guy..

Again, countless times I've tried to re-create the problem with everything working properly, other people as well with everything working properly. I'm pulling my hair out!

You can try the site out yourself to see if we can replicate the results..
http://www.minitrucker.org/bamfg.php
Login: stackoverflow
password: password

Everything is still crude with no CSS until I get all the code straight.. Thanks again.

EDIT *
I've changed the code to read:

```
$year =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['year']);
$make_model =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['make_model']);
$susp_type =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['susp_type']);
$interior =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['interior']);
$exterior =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['exterior']);
$audio_video =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['audiovideo']);
$wheels_tires =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['wheelstires']);
$suspension =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['suspension']);
$drivetrain =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['drivetrain']);
$nickname =  mysql_real_escape_string($vbulletin->GPC['nickname']);
```

Everything still works for me, I'm going to run more tests and see what happens. Thoughts?

Comment: Don't try to debug SQL by staring at code that generates SQL!  What's the final INSERT statement that this code executes?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with not properly escaping the values before putting them into the query. That would explain why it works for most people - except poor mister O'Brien.

Comment: DustyJoe: adding `mysql_real_escape_string` is not going to help you. What you want to do is reproduce the error before you start trying to fix it. Generally adding apostrophes screws up unescaped MySQL queries, so that might be the best way to reproduce it. Of course, using prepared statements would be the best way to go about it, but it is unfortunate that vbulletin is still using the legacy `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: It was just something I found when searching.. I will try and break it tonight.